# 3 select and collate the result of the query or organize (order by) by fields of the tables

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables and each one with different structure and number of different columns, but the first 4 columns are the same in all tables. For instance

#### Table 1

- Type
- id1
- id2
- Period
- FirstName
- LastName
- Value

#### table2

- Type
- id1
- id2
- Period
- Hours
- Days

#### table3

- Type
- id1
- id2
- Period
- Sex
- Address

I currently run a stored procedure

```
@Numeric period (6,0)

begin
select * from table1 where @ Period = 202109;
select * from table2 where @ Period = 202109;
select * from table3 where @ Period = 202109
end
```

... and I get the following results:

```
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
```

but what I need is the result to be like this:

```
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | FirstName | LastName | Value
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Hours | Days
Type | id1 | id2 | Period | Sex | Address
```

The fields `Type`, `id1`, `id2` and `Period` are the keys and the search criteria.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL or Microsoft SQL Server?...please update your post's tags accordingly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag as the code is clearly for SQL Server

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct your tables (preferably with some sample data) - help us to help you!